# Using selectors to target empty divs for removal

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I am trying to remove a div if it is empty. I have multiple divs with the same class and I want to remove it unless if it has text or images. I want it to ignore white spaces. I am using this:

```
    if($.trim($(".C1").html()) == "") {
  $(".C1").remove();
}
```

I then realized that I need to put in a unique id or class for each div I want to remove so I found that this works:

```
    if($.trim($(".C1").html()) == "") {
  $(".C1").remove();
}

    if($.trim($(".C2").html()) == "") {
  $(".C2").remove();
}
```

etc.

Is there a way to do this in one script? I tried doing this: .C1,.C2,.C3 etc but that only works if all of the divs are empty.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".C1").filter(':empty').remove()
```

or

```
$(".C2").filter(function() {
    return !this.innerHTML.trim();
}).remove();
```

Comment: thanks that function worked with the multiple selectors:

    $(".C1, .C2, .C3, .C4").filter(function() {
    return !this.innerHTML.trim();
    }).remove();

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery's [:empty](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector at this purpose.

```
// Removes every "empty" element.
$(":empty").remove();
```

That's a concrete example.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".foo, .bar, .baz")
    .filter(function(_, el) {
      return $(el).is(":empty");
    })
    .remove();

  console.log("Empty <div /> has been removed:", $(".foo").length == 0);
});
```

```html
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="bar">Not empty</div>
<div class="baz">
  <img src="/favicon.ico" />
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.C1, .C2').filter(function(){
     return !$.trim(this.innerHTML)
}).remove()
```

Comment: This is a great solution. I will use this one, thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to check the children count.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.C1').each(function(){
        if($(this).children().length == 0){
           $(this).remove();     
        }
    });
});
```

JSFiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/7udv7/1/